# Getting multiple items from object stdClass with foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays, object, foreach

I have my code here with the following methods:

```
$db = DB::getInstance();
$templates = $db->get('templates', array('user_id', '=', 'username'));
$templates = $templates->results();

echo '<pre>', print_r($templates), '</pre>';
```

Which returns this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [user_id] => username
            [template_id] => 2
            [template_name] => invoice1
            [template_description] => dear {{customer}},

            The {{item}} will cost {{price}}.
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [user_id] => username
            [template_id] => 3
            [template_name] => invoice2
            [template_description] => Dear {{customer}},

            You have selected {{package type}} service. Your {{item}} will cost {{price}}. 
        )
```

I can successfully get **one** template_description from the array with a foreach loop like this:

```
foreach($templates[1] as $key=>$value){           
        $value;          
    }
```

However, I have **multiple** template_descriptions I want to get and I'm not sure how. I'm not very familiar with foreach loops and objects.

IF I remove the number from '$templates' I get the error:

```
Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in C:\xampp\htdocs\email\test.php on line 15
```

Comment: `foreach($templates as $tpl) echo $tpl['template_description'];`

Comment: Why are iterating over just one result item at first? YOu should leave out the `[1]` in the loop (`$templates[1]`).

Comment: Without the [1] I get the error `Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in C:\xampp\htdocs\email\test.php on line 15`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you looping on only one element (the second object)? Remove `[1]` from `foreach`

```
foreach($templates[1] as $key=>$value){  
                  ^ Wrong way
```

Do this:

```
foreach($templates as $obj){           
         echo $obj->template_descrption;
    }
```

Comment: Because without it I get 'Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in C:\xampp\htdocs\email\test.php on line 15'

Comment: Yes change your loop to the one I provided and try again

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to omit the array key from your foreach, like so:

```
foreach($templates as $template){           
    echo $template->template_description;          
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach($templates as $template){
        foreach($template as $key=>$value){
                  echo $value;
         }
 }
```